# Plus character in URL transformed to space on a linux box

Tags: java, playframework

I'm testing Play! on Windows and Ubuntu. I have an action method that accepts an `email` parameter.

When I pass an email address that contains a plus sign (e.g. `abc+d@gmail.com`), on Windows it works as expected, while on my ubuntu box I get `abc d@gmail.com` assigned to the email parameter.

Has anyone encountered this situation before? I have no front-end proxy in front of Play - in both cases, it's direct access to the same version of Play (1.2.x-c40cf37, somewhat after 1.2.4), with the same `application.mode = dev`, pretty much the same config.

I can't debug the linux box - it's on an Amazon EC2 instance, and the Java debugging protocol is slow as hell for me. If I can't find another way, I'll have to install a local unbutu in a VM and debug it there. Before I do that, are there any other helpful tips I could try?

Comment: I never used Play!, but don't you need to URLencode the email address?

Comment: `+` on a URL is an escape for space. use `%20`.

Comment: @Bogdacutu - but on Windows it works well without any encoding ... I believe the browser encodes it anyways.

Comment: I can try encoding the URL myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is standard behaviour.

On a URL spaces can be represented by `+`. You need to escape it using `%20`.

Comment: This still doesn't explain the difference between Windows and Linux, but I get that in this case Windows might not follow the standard. I'll try encoding.

Comment: @ripper234 - This has more to do with how the different browsers do things.

Comment: That's odd though - I'm using the same browser on the same machine to access both servers.

Comment: Well, URL encoding worked. I still don't quite understand the difference between Windows and Ubuntu, but it works - thanks.

Comment: Note that a space can only be encoded as a plus sign in the query string, not in the URL path.