# Symbol "+" disappear inside input text when post form

Tags: php, ajax, forms, zend-framework, textinput

I am working with Zend Framework. I have a form with some fields, all of them `type="text"`, including an input called "Telephone". When submit, I am using Ajax to send data to Controller. Well here is my problem, if I type a `+` symbol, for example: 
`+34-666666666` the data I receive is `34-666666666`. The `+` symbol turns into a whitespace. This problem only happens with `+`, I have tried with all the symbols and theres no problem. I am going mad and I didn't found any solution in Google.

Comment: How exactly are you submitting the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode your GET/POST data as described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-content-type). The JavaScript [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function can be used with a little twist*:

> For application/x-www-form-urlencoded (POST), per specs, spaces are to
>   be replaced by '+', so one may wish to follow a encodeURIComponent
>   replacement with an additional replacement of "%20" with "+".

```
"&phone=" + encodeURIComponent("+34-666666666").replace(/%20/, "+");      // "&phone=%2B34-666666666"
"&phone=" + encodeURIComponent("+34-666666666 x123").replace(/%20/, "+"); // "&phone=%2B34-666666666+x123"
```

*Note: treatment of `+` character in a URL varies depending on whether it is used inside a path component or query string:

1. `http://example.com/page+1` -- file name `page+1`
2. `http://example.com/page%201` -- file name `page 1`
3. `http://example.com/?file=page+1` -- query string parameter `file=page 1`
4. `http://example.com/?file=page%201` -- query string parameter `file=page 1`

Answer (score 4):

The `+` symbol is used in URL's to represent whitespace. Your ajax submit is probably performing a GET request and the `+` in the URL string is getting transformed.
Sanitize your input via javascript before submitting the ajax request with `encodeURIComponent()`.

You might also find this question useful: [Plus character in URL transformed to space on a linux box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8960969/851811).

This question discusses `encodeURIComponent`: [How to encode a URL in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332872/851811)